# How to dynamically update one json object and put it back into the original json objects?

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

How to dynamically update one JSON object and put it back into the original JSON objects variable?

I have one variable with the following JSON data in it.

```json
test='[
  {
    "Name": "James",
    "Mobile": 12345678,
    "Gender": "Male",
    "Boolean": true,
    "Pet": "cat"
  },
  {
    "Name": "John",
    "Mobile": 1234567875,
    "Gender": "Male",
    "Boolean": true,
    "Pet": "rat"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Jennifer",
    "Mobile": 1234567890,
    "Gender": "Female",
    "Boolean": true,
    "Pet": "Dog"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Julia",
    "Mobile": 1234567890,
    "Gender": "Female",
    "Boolean": true,
    "Pet": "Dog"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Jeff",
    "Mobile": 9871234567890,
    "Gender": "Male",
    "Boolean": true,
    "Pet": "Fish"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Jones",
    "Mobile": 79871234567890,
    "Gender": "Female",
    "Boolean": true,
    "Pet": "Parrot"
  }
]'

items=$(echo "$test" | jq -c -r '.[]')
for item in ${items[@]}; do
    uName=$(echo $item | jq -r '.Name')
    if [ "$uName" == "John" ]; then
        echo "$item"
        echo " "
        modifiedTest=$(echo "$item" | jq  '.Name = "Tom"')
        modifiedTest=$(echo "$modifiedTest" | jq  '.Pet = "rabbit"')
        echo "$modifiedTest"
    fi    
done
```

Now let's say we have the below second JSON object from the above JSON objects

```json
{
  "Name": "John",
  "Mobile": 1234567875,
  "Gender": "Male",
  "Boolean": true,
  "Pet": "rat"
}
```

We have updated the above-picked JSON object fields with below

```json
{
  "Name": "Tom",
  "Mobile": 1234567875,
  "Gender": "Male",
  "Boolean": true,
  "Pet": "rabbit"
}
```

Now how can we add/update the above modified JSON object back into the original objects list variable 'test' at the exact position (2nd position in this case) but using a filter of 'Name=John' and in a dynamic way we don't know exact index position of this object using bash scripting?

Comment: Technically that's invalid JSON: you need the array brackets around the list of objects; and the last key:value in an object cannot have a trailing comma. Please fix that

Comment: If it is or is not JSON, with bash alone, you can only reliably treat the file as a text and do text manipulations on it. If you are prepared to leverage other executables from bash, then, I recommend you consider solving this problem using a language that has JSON support such as nodejs or python.

Comment: Have a look at [`select`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#select%28boolean_expression%29), the [update operator `|=`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Update-assignment%3A%7C%3D), as well as the [`map` filter](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#map%28x%29%2Cmap_values%28x%29), and try out something along the lines of `jq 'map(select(.Name == "John") |= (.Name = "Tom" | .Pet = "rabbit"))'`

Answer (score 1):

The tool `jq` can be used for JSON-manipulation:

```bash
jq '.[1].Name = "Tom" | .[1].Pet = "rabbit"' data.json
```

This will output the modified file on the console.

Note that in general `jq [filter] data.json > data.json` will not work and even when it seems to, overwriting the input file in this way should be avoided.  One option would be to use a shell variable:

```bash
json_data=$(jq '.[1].Name = "Tom" | .[1].Pet = "rabbit"' data.json)
echo $json_data > data.json
```

Another option would be to use a temporary file; still another would be to use a utility such as `sponge` in [moreutils](/questions/tagged/moreutils).

---

Note that your shown file is not valid JSON and so jq will not be able to read it as JSON. To fix it, I have surrounded everything by `[` and `]` and removed the extra comma in the `John` object.

Comment: What if we don't know the exact index position of this object and use a filter of 'Name=John' to get this object?          I have updated the question with this use case/scenario.

Answer (score 1):

> What if we don't know the exact index position of this object and use a filter of 'Name=John'

```
< data.json jq '
  (map(.Name)| index("John")) as $ix 
  | (select($ix)
     | .[$ix] |= (.Name = "Tom" | .Pet = "rabbit")) // .
' | sponge data.json
```

But you might want to backup data.json first.

Comment: Now I want to replicate this use-case in python3 as well. what would be the right python function or package with which we can achieve this in python3?